# How to get responses in expect (tcl)

Tags: tcl, buffer, expect

I am trying to query bluetoothctl using expect (tcl), but I cannot seem to get the bluetoothctl responses saved to a variable for processing with tcl.
For example:

```
spawn bluetoothctl

exp_send "scan on\n"

expect {
    -re {*NEW*} {
        set new $expect_out(0,string)
        puts "scan - found $new"
        exp_continue
    }
    timeout {
        exp_send "scan off\n"
        exp_send "quit\n"
        close
        wait
        puts "EXPECT timed out"
    }
}
```

The result of the above is along the lines of:

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 10:08:B1:57:35:62 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device EB:06:EF:34:04:B7 MPOW-059
[bluetooth]# 
EXPECT timed out
```

So nothing is output until expect is closed. I have been trying this all day with different combinations but - I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Edit: changed the regex to (.NEW.) and that works. So now I get:

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 10:08:B1:57:35:62 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device EB:06:EF:34:04:B7 MPOW-059
[bluetooth]# scan - found scan on
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 10:08:B1:57:35:62 Discovering: yes
[NEW
```

which is everything except the bit that I wanted to retrieve viz:

```
[NEW] Device EB:06:EF:34:04:B7 MPOW-059
```

Comment: Annoyingly `bluetoothctl` adds color codes and other control characters to the output, which makes it hard to script. Furthermore, it doesn't honor the TERM variable. So the usual trick of setting TERM=dumb doesn't help. Aside from that, `{*NEW*}` is not a valid regular expression. You may prefer the `-gl` switch instead of `-re`.

Answer (score 1):

That regular expression looks syntactically wrong. If you did `{.*NEW.*}` then it might work. Assuming that those three letters are actually being output by `bluetoothctl` with no control characters mixed in. (It'd be weird to do that, but some code *is* weird…)

Apart from that, have you tried the diagnostic mode for expect? Pass the `-d` flag to the expect program when you start it to get *lots* of output about what it is really seeing and looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer appears to be:

1. The expect_out(buffer) is cleared by a puts statement
2. Find all the possible responses expected making sure that the expected response specifies the whole line.
3. Save the buffer in a variable if required
4. Issue a puts statement to clear the buffer

So:

```
expect {
    "Hello" {
         puts "$expect_out(buffer)"
         exp_continue
    }
    -re (How.*) {
         set answer $expect_out(buffer)
         if {$answer == "How are you"} {
             exp_send "Well thank you"
         }
    }
```

or, in the example above:

```
expect {    
    "Discovery started" {
        puts $expect_out(buffer)
        exp_continue
    }
    -re (.CHG.*) {
        puts $expect_out(buffer)
        exp_continue
    }
    -re (.NEW.*) {
        set new $expect_out(buffer)
```